# How to stay signed in on IE mobile?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I always need to sign in to the main site when using Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7.5.

I have cookies turned on, so I thought this would work well and leave me signed-in, just like the desktop version.

Does anyone else have this problem?

I am using Google as my OpenID authenticator.

Comment: pardon the silly question, but when you sign in with google, do you check "remember me"?

Comment: I just left it as the default (which I think is signed in), but I don't think this makes a difference as you can sign out of Google and still be signed into SE. Anyway it has left me signed in from yesterday (even after  a reboot), So perhaps my SE cookie from last week had expired. Will see what happens next week and close this if needed.

Comment: I don't experience this, perhaps might be Google specific. Although I sometimes do need to log in again, but it doesn't bother me. Could be one or two weeks, but I sometimes delete the history which might impose the cookie being removed...

Comment: I'm using Facebook auth and IE9 Mobile. Never need to signin again. Changing to Desktop version keep signin too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to have been working for a week now without any problems. For the few times that I had seen it, the cause was likely an expired/deleted cookie.

Mod, please tag as [status-norepro](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-norepro).